# Why exception handling does not work in PHP

Tags: php, exception

Why it is not displaying Error!????

```
        try {
                $i = 9 / 0;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Error !';
            }
```

Comment: Because a warning !== an exception

Comment: Because `$i = 9 / 0;` in PHP *does **not** throw an exception*. Instead it warns you: `Warning: Division by zero in FILE on line X`.

Comment: in C# this used to throw exception.